# IE10 - Using CSS style height and adding a border when focus on a SELECT element requires users to double click SELECT element

Tags: css, height, border, internet-explorer-10

I have a FORM with a SELECT element inside it.

```
<form name="something">
    <select>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And the CSS:

```
select
{  
    height:20px;
} 

form select:focus
{
    border: #ffdead solid 2px;
}
```

What I am doing is ensuring that all SELECTs are always the same height, but when a user TABS through elements on the page, I want the SELECT to have a border when focus.

This works in most browsers, but in IE10 when a user clicks on the SELECT, the select is not expanded - it is focused, and the user must click again to expand the options.

Here is a JSFIDDLE to see how it works in IE10:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtKGE/3/

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it has more to do with setting select's **border** in css :focus

You can try using this in your fiddle and see it works

```
form select:focus
{
    color:red;
}
```

Anyway it's a weird one since in other than your fiddle, I can set up other border properties like border-color or border-style and it only breaks again whenever I set up border-width like in this css

```
select:focus 
{
    border-color:#666666;
    border-style:solid;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Daniel